# Maven 'resources' folder not found

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

On the first step, I have a dynamic web project in Eclipse with folder `resources` in `WebContent`

Now I like to try Maven, I use the 'convert dynamic web project to maven' with right click on the project and **configure** => **convert to maven**

I set the `pom.xml` with dependence for the jar and it's ok.

I run the application but I don't see the resources folder of project in my WebContent with all css, js, ....

I changed the default folder `src / app / resources` for maven (i think) by `WebContent / resources`, but it's not working

Do you have an idea for me?

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Immo2_0</groupId>
<artifactId>Immo2_0</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Immo2_0</name>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/c3p0/c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.codemodel/codemodel -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.codemodel</groupId>
        <artifactId>codemodel</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-digester/commons-digester -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/javax.activation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b06</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0-v_771</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsonschema2pojo/jsonschema2pojo-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-alpha4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.extensions/primefaces-extensions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz-jobs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.rome/rome -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.rome</groupId>
        <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.SP1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.servlet/weld-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.facelets/jsf-facelets -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My folder :
[image]

Comment: First strong recommendation is: Follow convention over configuration and do not change the default unless you exactly what you are doing which obviously is not the case...means `src/main/java` production code ..`src/main/webapp` the parts for WAR file etc. `src/main/resources` resources and unit test code `src/test/java`...etc...

Answer (score 1):

The default structure (which I strongly reccomend you use) for Maven is:

```
src/
src/main
src/main/webapp
src/main/webapp/index.jsp
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
src/main/resources
src/main/resources/test.properties
```

The maven war plugin will take care of the rest, and produce a war that looks like:

```
     0 Wed Aug 15 12:47:12 BST 2018 META-INF/
   130 Wed Aug 15 12:47:10 BST 2018 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Wed Aug 15 12:47:12 BST 2018 WEB-INF/
     0 Wed Aug 15 12:47:12 BST 2018 WEB-INF/classes/
    52 Wed Aug 15 12:46:22 BST 2018 index.jsp
     0 Wed Aug 15 12:47:12 BST 2018 WEB-INF/classes/test.properties
   215 Wed Aug 15 12:46:22 BST 2018 WEB-INF/web.xml
     0 Wed Aug 15 12:47:12 BST 2018 META-INF/maven/
     0 Wed Aug 15 12:47:12 BST 2018 META-INF/maven/com.greg/
     0 Wed Aug 15 12:47:12 BST 2018 META-INF/maven/com.greg/war-example/
   716 Wed Aug 15 12:46:22 BST 2018 META-INF/maven/com.greg/war-example/pom.xml
   111 Wed Aug 15 12:47:12 BST 2018 META-INF/maven/com.greg/war-example/pom.properties
```

You can create example projects from archetypes, I created the one above with:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Comment: Agreed - do not deviate from the standard.  That's how Maven works.